# External List - changing a column to dropdown in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, external-list, jslink

I'm on Sharepoint foundation 2013.

I have a external list (based on a WCF)

For the new and edit form, I'd like to have some columns to be a dropdown (list to be populated from another WCF)

Is JSlink the only option? (seems like there will be lots of mucking around using JSLink) Not sure if there are other solutions that's cleaner and simpler? (e.g. SP Designer etc)

Thanks!!! (Sorry to ask the same question again.. recommended by a colleague saying sometimes it works, please let me know if I need to remove the old post)

Answer (score 1):

I’ve found that using an External List with BDC creates mostly single line of text fields depending on how the SQL fields are setup.

A possible option might be to create a custom list and then just add an external content type linked to the ‘lookup’ table field and this will then allow the users to only select the appropriate values.

Hope this gives you some guidance.